# What is the most ideal way to serialize a set of filters to used by Backbone.JS's Router.navigate()?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

Let's say you have some filters:

```
{department_id: 4, vendor_id:8, start_date: "2014-04-03"}
```

What would be the best way to serialize this data to be used in a URL with Backbone.JS's Router.history()?

By "best", I mean something that can be easily serialized/de-serialized and looks neat when appended to the URL.

Thanks!

Comment: i see the only way :) keep filter as Model and provide it to the Router helper method to convert to key=value and then use `navigate` to keep URL update

Comment: @Evgeniy Could you please elaborate about this Router helper method? I did not see anything in the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, it's not method "from the box", bb Router should be extended with it. Imagine, smth like Controller manage filter model and initialize router, on init you provide this filter model to router as param and hook up model change with convert method saveFilterState. On model change u have current state, toJSON() will give you hash like { key: value }. Simple loop for in will return you string like key=value&... . This string will be used as new Url to navigate with Router.navigate